# Is there a way to receive information on execution order(Specifically for sieve of erastothenes)?

Tags: algorithm, debugging, haskell, recursion, trace

I am attempting to understand one of the prime number algorithms enumerated here: https://wiki.haskell.org/index.php?title=Prime_numbers&oldid=36858#Postponed_Filters_Sieve, specifically:

```
primes :: [Integer]
primes = 2: 3: sieve (tail primes) [5,7..]
  where 
    sieve (p:ps) xs = h ++ sieve ps [x | x <- t, x `rem` p /= 0]  
                                    -- or:  filter ((/=0).(`rem`p)) t
                      where (h,~(_:t)) = span (< p*p) xs
```

So conceptually I understand how this algorithm works (sieve of Erastothenes), start with 2,3, and a list of numbers, then eliminate any that are greater than the previous square and divisible by any below it.

But I'm having a hard time following along with the nested recursive step (prime calles sieve on primes, which calls sieve on primes which...)

I understand that this works due to lazy evaluation, and it demonstrably produces the right result, but I am incapable of following it.

So for example if I were to run `take 5 primes` what would actually happen:

e.g (I will refer to the result of the take operation as t for ease of reading/reasoning):

Step 1)
primes returns a list `[2,3, xs]`

so `t` is `[2,3, take 3 xs]`

where `xs` is `sieve (tail primes) [5,7..]`

Step 2)
`tail primes` is `3:xs`
where `xs` is `sieve (tail primes) [5,7..]`
etc

so t should now be [2,3,3,3,3,3...]

I have little trouble following sieve itself...

So I guess I have two questions.

1) How exactly does this algorithm actually work, and where/why is my trace wrong

2) Is there a way, generally, in Haskell to figure out what order things are running in? Maybe print a recursion tree? Or at the very least drop in a debugger halt?

Comment: Mind that `=` is **not an assignment**. It is an equation, so the `primes` in the `tail primes` is the **same** one as the one you are constructing at that time...

Comment: right, so the tail only really removes the 2 from the same list, which calls itself recursively, always just removing the 2, which is where the infinite list of 3s comes from

Comment: How could `sieve ... [5, 7, ..]` ever possibly return `3:...`?  `sieve` can only produce elements from its second input in its output.

Comment: I guess my point is more:

sieve (tail primes) xs => sieve (3:(sieve (tail primes))) => sieve (3:3(sieve (tail primes)))......

Comment: `sieve (tail primes) xs` does not reduce to `sieve (3 : sieve (tail primes))`.

Comment: primes => 2:3:(stuff)
tail primes => 3:(stuff)
sieve (tail primes) other => sieve (3:stuff) other
substituting stuff: sieve (tail primes) [5,7..]
so sieve (tail primes) [5, 7..] => sieve(3:(sieve (tail primes) [5, 7..])) [5,7..]
etc

Comment: Are you pretty familiar with lazy evaluation?  If not, I would suggest leaving this program be while you get more familiar -- this is a quite complex example -- I have many years experience with haskell and it would still take me quite some time to work out the evaluation order.  Maybe consider the classic fibonacci example very closely: `fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)`.

Comment: You can also have a look at [`Debug.Trace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html) which will print some text the first time a thunk is evaluated.  It can be a good guide for developing your intuition.

Answer (score 2):

I took the liberty of de-optimizing and clarifying the algorithm a little bit:

```
primes :: [Integer]
primes = 2 : sieve primes [3 ..]

sieve :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
sieve []     xs = xs -- degenerate case for testing
sieve (p:ps) xs = h ++ sieve ps [x | x <- t, x `rem` p /= 0]
  where (h, t) = span (< p*p) xs
```

This is the same base logic, but it does a lot more redundant work (a constant factor per output value, though) than the version you provided.  I think that's a simpler starting point, and once you understand how this version works, it's easy to see what the optimizations do.  I also pulled `sieve` into its own definition.  It didn't use anything from its enclosing scope, and the ability to test it standalone might help with understanding what's going on.

If you'd like to peek into how evaluation proceeds, you can use the [`Debug.Trace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html) module.  The two functions I use most from it are [`trace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:trace) and [`traceShow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:traceShow), depending on the value I want to see.

So, let's get a bit of tracing info from `sieve`:

```
import Debug.Trace

primes :: [Integer]
primes = 2 : sieve primes [3 ..]

sieve :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
sieve []     xs = trace "degenerate case for testing" xs
sieve (p:ps) xs = traceShow (p, h) $ h ++ sieve ps [x | x <- t, x `rem` p /= 0]
  where (h, t) = span (< p*p) xs
```

And to test it out:

```
ghci> take 10 primes
[2(2,[3])
,3(3,[5,7])
,5,7(5,[11,13,17,19,23])
,11,13,17,19,23(7,[29,31,37,41,43,47])
,29]
```

Well, that's a lot less clear than hoped.  When ghci prints out a result, it uses the `Show` instance for the result's type. And the `Show` instance for `[Integer]` is lazy itself, so the printing of the list is getting interleaved with the tracing.  To do better, let's have ghci produce a value that won't be output until after the tracing is complete.  The `sum` should do:

```
ghci> sum $ take 10 primes
129
```

That was..  less than useful.  Where'd the tracing go?  Well, remember that the tracing functions are *very* impure. Their explicit goal is to produce side effects.  But GHC doesn't respect side effects.  It assumes that all functions are pure.  One result of that assumption is that it can store the result of evaluating expressions.  (Whether it does so or not depends on whether there is a shared reference or CSE optimizations kick in. In this case, `primes` itself is a shared reference.)

Maybe if we ask it to evaluate further than it has so far?

```
ghci> sum $ take 20 primes
(11,[53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113])
639
```

Ok, the tracing is separate from ghci's output as desired.  But it's not really very informative at that point.  To get a better picture, it needs to start back at the beginning.  To do that, we need to get ghci to unload the definition of primes so that it will re-evaluate it from scratch.  There are a bunch of ways to do this, but I'll demonstrate a method that has some additional ways to be useful.

```
ghci> :load *sieve.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( sieve.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
```

By putting the `*` in front of the file name in the `:load` command, I instructed ghci to interpret the source from scratch, regardless of its current state.  This works in this case because it forces a re-interpretation even though the source hasn't changed.  It also is useful when you want to use `:load` on a source that has compiled output in the current directory, and have it interpret the whole module, not just load the compiled code.

```
ghci> sum $ take 10 primes
(2,[3])
(3,[5,7])
(5,[11,13,17,19,23])
(7,[29,31,37,41,43,47])
129
```

Now, let's get into how the algorithm actually works. The first thing to look into what the components of the tracing output are. The first element is the prime whose multiples are being sieved out of the potential outputs.  The second element is the list of values being accepted as primes because they're less than `p*p`, and all non-primes less than that have already been removed from the candidate list.  The mechanics of that should be familiar from any study of the sieve of Eratosthenes.

The calls to `sieve` start with `sieve primes [3..]`.  The first place laziness critically comes into play is the pattern match on the first argument.  The `(:)` constructor is already known, so the pattern matches `p` to the literal `2`, and `ps` to an unevaluated expression. It's very important that it's unevaluated, because this call to `sieve` is what calculates the value. If it forced it to be evaluated to proceed, it would introduce a circular data dependency, which results in an infinite loop.

As the tracing indicates, the prime being used to remove elements from the candidates is 2.  The call to `span` splits the input `[3..]` into `([3], [4..])`.  `h` is `[3]`, as demonstrated by the tracing output.  So the result of the call to `sieve` is `[3] ++ <recursive call to sieve>`.  This is the second place laziness critically comes into play in the algorithm. The implementation of `(++)` doesn't do anything at all with its second argument until it has already produced the prefix of the list.  This means that before the recursive call to `sieve` is evaluated, it's known that `ps` refers to a thunk that evaluates to `[3] ++ <recursive call>`.

That's enough information to handle the recursive call to `sieve`. Now, `p` is matched to `3`, `ps` is matched to a thunk, and the logic continues.  The tracing should illustrate what's going on at this point.

Now, the version you started with does a few things to optimize.  First, it observes that the first element of `t` is always going to equal `p*p`, and it uses pattern matching to eliminate that element without doing any remainder calculation on it. This is a small saving per prime examined, but it is a clear saving.

Second, it skips filtering out the multiples of two, and just doesn't generate them in the first place. This reduces the amount of elements generated to be filtered later by a factor of two, *and* it reduces the number of filters being applied to each odd element by one.

As an aside, note that the stacking filter behavior is actually algorithmically significant, and not faithful to the sieve of Eratosthenes as described in literature.  For further discussion of this, see [The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf) by Melissa O'Neill.